# phpmyadmin 4 downgrade to 3

Tags: phpmyadmin, downgrade

I'm looking for a way to downgrade my phpMyAdmin from version 4.0.5 to let say 3.5 or 3.6 or sth. like that. Does anyone know how to do it? Is it possible without losing all my databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of installing version 3.5.8.2. Refer to http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install.

If you have not installed phpMyAdmin configuration storage tables that are specific to version 4, you have nothing else to do. Of course, it depends on the URL you are using to visit phpMyAdmin, and whether you installed version 4.0 by yourself or used a prepackaged installation.

I don't see why you would lose your databases by doing so.

Comment: I installed it by executing: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` so now I should probably go for .tar.gz version of phpmyadmin 3.6 and install it manually

Comment: phpMyAdmin 3.6 does not exist.

Comment: Good point I just mean version before upgrade to 4.0, I thought it was 3.6. Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

When I was looking to downgrade, I found that the missing step seemed to be changing the Apache Alias to refer to the older folder.

If you are using a package like say WAMP, the default install folder for the code will be in

```
root/apps/phpmyadmin3.2.0.1
root/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4
```

When you simply type in localhost/phpmyadmin in your browser, Apache will redirect you to whatever the current install is. This is done via an Alias Directory. If you want to revert to an older version, then all you will likely need to do is change the rewrite to point to the older folder.

The file itself probably looks something like:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/Server/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/"
#// Make sure these point to the version of the program you want to run.

<Directory "C:/Server/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```