# Using ancient PHP and Mysql versions with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I need to use Telekom Hosting for a Wordpress project and i am stuck with ancient PHP (5.4.45), mysql (5.0.96-CM4all-PRO-0ubuntu1-log) and phpmyadmin (2.11.11.3) versions. Is there any way to get all of this set up in a recent MAMP (non-pro) version?

I already got the PHP version to work, but with this I can only use phpliteadmin and cannot import my database. Can I enable an old phpmyadmin with MAMP?

I want to use MAMP as a mirrored testing server.

Thanks for your help! (I use Mac OS X 10.12.6 btw)

Comment: Does it have to be MAMP? Can't you just set up an apache server with the PHP module?

Comment: I am using MAMP because of the usability as a offline testing environment and dont have that much experience setting up a apache server. Would you recommend trying int?

Comment: Well MAMP is short for "My apache - MySQL - PHP" and since you already have strict requirements for the other 2 then it's probably easier to install Apache on its own.

Comment: Mac comes with a ready to use Apache/ PHP setup which is currently 5.6, did you looked at: https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/older-versions/

Comment: downgrading phpmyadmin is answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747846/phpmyadmin-4-downgrade-to-3

Comment: Yes, actually downgrading phpmyadmin isnt that issue, but MAMP disables phpmyadmin when I downgrade my PHP version to 5.4.45 and forces me to  use phpliteadmin...

Comment: I will look at the apache installation on Sierra. Maybe it is the way to go. Thank you!